# asp.net - best way to display 5 records at a time using two pages

Tags: asp.net

1. I have to create a asp.net page that shows 5 records, stays for 10 seconds, shows the next 5 for another 10 seconds and return to the first 5 record when reaching last record.
2. I need to retrieve data from database every 5 min only to do refresh for the displayed record. I want to do this in 2 different pages - for example one page does all the work and the second page only displays data without doing anything with the database. So whenever there is any problem with the database the first page will keep on showing the last records.

I figured out the first part by using a grid view and timer but I struggled with the second.

It is a notice page like flight information board idea at airports.

I hope you can help me with it or tell me what is the best way to do it.

Comment: yes I used asp.net ajax timer control ,,, I will send u my code when I will be @ office... I want to use two pages so in case any error come or problem happen the display page will continue showing the last fetched record and the other page will send an alert through user email... simply I dont want to show the user that there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a usercontrol inside your aspx page, then in your aspx page you can have it check the database and retrieve the data pass it to your usercontrol and databind.  If your aspx page cannot retrieve data then it wouldn't databind your usercontrol so it will not change its data.

usercontrol

```
private DataTable _newdata = null;
public DataTable NewData
{
    get { return _newdata; }
    set { _newdata = value; }
}
public override void DataBind()
{
     if(NewData.Rows.Count > 0)
     {
         mygridview.DataSource = NewData;
         mygridview.DataBind();
      }
}
```

Comment: I will try this code and let u know how it goes ,,, but is it possible to just show the record on separate div instead of gridview ....

Comment: you don't have to use a usercontrol, i just added that because you were specifying 2 pages.  You could have all in the one aspx, but always make sure that data is there before databinding.  You can use what ever you want and if it has data then you do what you need accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment doing it on client side using Java Script/JQuery. JQuery [JCycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) will do it for you

Comment: does not answer the question. E.g. how do you know there is a database problem from the client side?

Comment: The Jcyle is good for fliping the page but I want to disply the record on diffrent div like each 5 record on a sepreate div ,,, I dont know how to do it... to make it simpl how I can disply record without using data control of asp.net ... I dont want to use gridview or data grid